# check if 2 pointers are null or not

Tags: c++, pointers, null

is it safe to check this way if both are nullptr, or there is a better way ?
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *x;
    int *y;
    
    if (not (x or y))
    {
      std::cout<<"both are nullptr";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK. I would write it as `if(!x && !y)` which is straighter and easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: `x`, `y` are not initialized, so your test leads to UB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should use the actually operator names(`!` and `||`) to increase readability(it might seem to you like this reduces readability, but once you get ahold of all of the operators, you'll find it easier this way).

And yes, this is a valid way to check if both pointer are valid, but it is a bit confusing at first(once again, readability). It's better to use the `&&`(`and`) operator:

```
if (!x && !y)
```

This checks if both x **and** y are not null-pointers.

Comment: About readability, I would say it is just a style (as long as we really use their word meaning and not do stuff like `int bitand ref = some_var;`). I found words more readable than symbols here (even if I use symbol mostly for consistency).

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic [Law 1 of De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (negation of disjunction) of boolean algebra, so it's exactly the same as `if(!x && !y)`.

That said, unless you have an ISO language problem and can't use `!` and `||`, try not to use the alternative operator representations, they confuse people.